# Symfony2 basic login authentification - Bad Credential

Tags: php, symfony

I have a bad credential in a very simple login authentification.
There is no Entity containing the login and password.

I tried to login on both 'user' and 'admin' with 'password' and 'adminpass' as password.

I am accessing my login form by this url: http://localhost/my_projects/Symphony_projects/site/web/app_dev.php/login

Here is my security.yml

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: password, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

firewalls:
    login_area:
        pattern: ^/login$
        anonymous: true
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: false 
        form_login:
            login_path:    /login
            check_path:    /login_check

access_control:
    - { path: admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Tanks a lot for your times!

Comment: Hi ! From which URL/pattern are you accessing your login system ? Which credentials did you try ?

Comment: I edited the post so others can directly see answers, thanks for your interest in my probleme. :)